# DOM - Find text between arbitrarily nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Suppose my DOM looks something like this (purely fictional example):

```
<div>
  <img id="img1" />
  Text 1
</div>

<img id="img2" />

<div>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <div>
    <img id="img3" />
  </div>
  <img id="img4" />
</div>
```

What I'm attempting to do is to find all text (if any) between consecutive  elements independent of nesting level (so in this case, I'd find `Text1` between `#img1` and `#img2`, `Text 2` between `#img2` and `#img3`, and nothing/an empty string between `#img3` and `#img4`)

I don't know ahead of time how the dom is going to be structured.

I've tried using JQuery's [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/), but that only seems to work for sibling nodes.

Comment: you mean between consecutive images not elements, right ?

Comment: yes, consecutive elements of a specific type (in this case imgs)

Comment: You should walk the DOM in a depth-first manner starting at your `img`, and manually collect text until you reach another `img`.

Comment: Here is a lazy way to do it: http://jsbin.com/mokazohari/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: unfortunately this lazy way doesn't do quite what I need - I need to know between which img tags each part of text is

Comment: @Abraxas [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26874402/128165) returns the starting element, the ending element and the text between them. Have a look at the console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my solution is more closely achieves what you specified. This is also using `contents()` but does the traversing/filtering too, based on the ids.

```
function textBetweenIds(firstId, lastId) {
    var texts = [],
        betweenIds = false,
        recurse = function ($item) {
            $item.each(function() {
                var text,
                    $item = $(this),
                    itemId = $item.attr("id"),
                    contents = $item.contents();
                if (itemId == firstId) {
                    betweenIds = true;
                } else if (itemId == lastId) {
                    betweenIds = false;
                }
                if (contents.length == 0 && betweenIds) {
                    text = $item.text().trim();
                    if (text != undefined && text.length > 0) {
                        texts.push(text);
                    }
                }
                recurse(contents);
            });
            return texts;
        };
    recurse($("body"));
    return texts;
}

result = textBetweenIds("img1", "img3");
// result: ["Text 1", "Text 2"]
```

Comment: You don't need `$item.attr("id")` using a function for something that already exists. `$item.id`

Comment: @EasyBB: `$item.id` would not work. But you're right, the `attr()` call is unneccessary, I could use `this.id` instead.

Comment: that too. I don't use jQuery at all anymore so I forget what exactly $(this) returns in all actuality, which I figured it was an HTMLElement so it would have the property id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) method which returns all child nodes including textnodes.
This way, doing `$('body *').contents().addBack()` returns a flattened representation of the DOM.

Now, you can iterate between `img` (*or whatever tag you want*) elements and get the textnodes (*having a `nodeType` of 3*)

```js
function textBetweenTags(tag){
  var contents = $('body *').contents().addBack(),
      allOfType = contents.filter(tag),
      count = allOfType.length,
      map = allOfType.map(function(){return contents.index( this );}),
      texts = [];
  
  
  for (var i = 0, l = map.length-1; i < l; i++){
    var start = map[i],
        end = map[i+1],
        textnodes = contents.slice(start,end).get().filter(function(item,index){return item.nodeType===3;});
    texts.push( {
      start: contents[start],
      end: contents[end],
      text: $.trim($(textnodes).text()) 
    });
  }
  return texts.filter(function(item,index){return item.text !== '';});
}

var texts = textBetweenTags('img');

console.log(texts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="img1" />
  Text 1
</div>

<img id="img2" />

<div>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <div>
    <img id="img3" />
  </div>
  <img id="img4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Although this answer generally solves my question, [zord's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26874582/2245120) more closely matches the specifics of what I needed (which admittedly might have been because of poor clarification on my question), so I've chosen to accept that one.