# get text between two images

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simpler way to catch the text between two images which haven't a same parent element?
I'm making a userscript for a webpage.
Like:

```
<div id="content"></div>
     <div style="text-align:center"><img src="" alt=""></div>
     <a>some text</a>
     <img src="" alt="">
     <div style="text-align:left">more text</div>
</div>
```

How to get the text between the 1st image and 2nd image of the div content. I don't know exactly the correct structure because maybe the text and the images could be inside of div or a nodes. I'd rather not use libraries

Comment: Could you provide more details on the conditions?

Comment: You could wrap the entire thing in a `div` with a classname and use that to get the inner text. Is this possible with what you are looking for?

Comment: Just give that element a class `<div class="text-node">some text</div>` That way you can just use `$('.text-node').html()`

Comment: Is this the pattern that will ALWAYS show up?

Comment: No. I don't know. Sometimes yes sometimes not

Comment: Is it just divs that don't contain images?

Comment: You should provide a few more case examples so that maybe we can see the best option for you.

Comment: You also said it's for post, meaning if it is for post they should follow the same syntax in every post besides what the user writes in. I can write something but need to know the pattern that will most likely show up.

Comment: Have you read the answers to the question here "[DOM - Find text between arbitrarily nested elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873332/dom-find-text-between-arbitrarily-nested-elements)"? I'm not entirely convinced it's a duplicate, but I think it might be.

Comment: So, do the answers to that question successfully answer your own? If not, consider explaining where/how they fail to address your requirements (just because a question is *similar* doesn't mean that they can't be different/non-duplicate). Though the onus is now on you to clearly explain how your question is different, and how the answers to the other question fail in this case. Include code, any error message, use of a different/no libraries...

Comment: Library = more time with family (With jQuery it would be just like that!)

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if each image were always wrapped inside a container.  If it were mine, I'd use JQuery.wrap() to make sure they were, then everything else would be much smoother.  Heck, I might even unwrap them when I'm done ;)

Comment: Finally I found a simple solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to handle the `<img>` tags as quotes around text you want to extract.

The easiest way to do that is to just replace the `<img>` tag with something not likely repeated in the text, and use that character as a delimiter. I'll show you how using jQuery. If you need it done in pure JS than you'll have to convert this.

First, make a copy of the HTML.

```
var html = $('<div>').append($("#content").html());
```

Next, replace all `<img>` tags with a special character (or other token you know is unique).

```
html.find("img").replaceWith("<div>~</div>");
```

Once you've done that you can just match text between those delimiters like this.

```
var str = html.text();
var rx = /~([^~]+)~/g;
var match = rx.exec(str);
```

To find all matches just repeat.

```
while(match != null)
{
    alert(match[1]);
    match = rx.exec(str);    
}
```

It's possible to do the same with a unique phrase like `@img@` instead of a single character, but a single character is way easier.

Here's a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/etx1z6ov/2/

Comment: Yes this is a good logic, and i think that my solution with loops is too risky

Comment: And if I better use @img@, how would it be the regex? Because I think that the ~ sign or another single sign is too risky

Comment: But I realized that it's better with `split('~')` instead of regex

Answer (score 2):

Improving Mathew's answer with pure javascript:

```
var html = document.getElementById('content').cloneNode(true);
var imgs = html.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var textSep = document.createTextNode('@img@');
    imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(textSep, imgs[i]);
}
var texts = html.textContent;
texts = texts.split('@img@');
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not the best, I just put it here just for info

1 - Go down

2 - Go to the next sibling

3 - If there isn't, go up and the next sibling.

Repeat.

It's like walking through a valley like this :D

```
\                 div#content                     /
 \txt/\  div   /\ div /\    div     /\txt/\  div /
       \  a   /  \txt/  \    a     /       \img2/
        \img1/           \txt/\txt/
```

Well, after several hours I found out, and made the algorithm:

```
function textAfterElem (el, nextEl) {
    var txt = "";

    while(true){
        //go down
        while(el.firstChild) {
            el = el.firstChild;
            if (el == nextEl) {return txt;}
        }
        txt += el.textContent; // extract
        //go next
        if (el.nextSibling) {
            el = el.nextSibling;
            if (el == nextEl) {return txt;}
        }else{
            //go up
            while(!el.nextSibling) {
                el = el.parentNode;
                if (el == document.body) {return txt;} // for security
            }
            if (el.nextSibling) {
                el = el.nextSibling; // go next
                if (el == nextEl) {return txt;}
            }else{
                return txt; // for security
            }
        }
    }
    return txt;
}
```

And it could be used not only with images but any element

Comment: Well this solution is kind of risky if the loop get out of control

Answer (score 0):

A simple erase and split works too:

```
html.replace(/<(?!img\b)[^>]*>/g, '').split(/<img\b[^>]*>/)
```

With your example the result is:

```
["↵     ", "↵     some text↵     ", "↵     more text↵"]
```